# isapi rewrite 3 changing # character into a %23 in browser

Tags: isapi-rewrite

All,

Trying to redirect too a URL like below:

```
http://domain/something/index.html#some/more/stuff.html
```

only problem here is that the # is getting changed into a %23 and it does not fine this URL.

Am i supposed to treat this differently?

Thanks in advance

Citty

Answer (score 0):

Was missing the no escape tag [NE]

citty